# Move div based off of image size calculation

Tags: jquery, css, image, position

I'm masking an image with a div that has overflow hidden. I'm trying to limit the amount the image can be dragged by having the containment set to a larger div that everything sits in. I'm having a problem getting the containment div to reposition itself up and left based off of half of the images width/height. The goal is for the user to be able to drag the image to any position without being able to drag it beyond the edge of the image.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/uEBDW/20/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="window">
        <img src="http://alumniconnections.com/olc/filelib/COU/cpages/48/Library/chicago_skyline.jpg" class="drag img" alt="chicago" width="300" height="300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
body {
    background: white;
    margin: 30px;
}

#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

#window {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #6D6D6D;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: move;
    position: absolute;
    /* Stop blue overlay on photo */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(".drag").draggable({
        containment: "#container"
    });

$('.img').each(function() {
    var imageWidth = $(this).width();
    var imageHeight = $(this).height();
    alert('Width: ' + $(this).width() + '\nHeight: ' + $(this).height()); // For testing purposes only
    var positionTop = -(imageHeight / 2);
    var positionLeft = -(imageWidth / 2);
    alert('Top: ' + positionTop + '\nLeft: ' + positionLeft); // For testing purposes only
});

$('#container').css({
    'top': positionTop + 'px',
    'left': positionLeft + 'px'
});

});
```

Comment: You are trying to use `positionTop` and `positionLeft` in a different scope than where they are defined, so they are undefined and it's throwing an error

Comment: What Browser are you targeting? Seems to work in Chrome, but not in IE - so I'm assuming IE. Correct?

Comment: Needs to work in IE7 and up. It's not working in Firefox, which is what I use. :)

Comment: In the jsfiddle you should be able to drag the up and left 150px, but currently that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the console window when running jsfiddle and you'll see some errors as you're trying to access variables out of scope.

However, what I would do is use the "stop" event and do your positioning. See [event-stop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop) for more information. Below I'm looking to see what the parent container "window" is set to and then checking if the new top position is greater than it. If true, then set the position to half the parent height.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(".drag").draggable({
        containment: "#container",
        stop: function(e,ui) {
            var $me = $(ui.helper[0]);
            var $container = $me.closest('div');
            console.log("Top: " +ui.position.top);
            //console.log("Height: " +$me.height());
            var newTop = $me.parent().height() / 2;
            console.log(newTop);            
            if(ui.position.top > newTop){
                console.log('Setting top to: ' + newTop);
                $me.css({'top' : newTop + 'px','left': '0px' });
            }
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only reposition the div after the image has been dragged once? The container div needs to be in place on page load so the first time there is a drag event the image can move accordingly. I understand the concept of scope but I'm afraid I don't understand how to get around that in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I might be missing your goal. However, the above code will fire every time the dragged item is in a stopped state. If the image position is greater then half the size of the parent container, then it will re-position it in the middle - which was what I thought you asked for..??

Comment: I've gotten rid of the out of scope errors and updated the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/uEBDW/ 

The problem now is the window div now jumps up and left, not the container div.

Comment: Having negative values for "positionTop" and "positionLeft" will move it off the screen. Set a border around your div's and it will show you where things are lining up.

Comment: Thanks. I need the containing div to move up and to the left but not the window div. I'm trying to make some room for the image to be able to be dragged toward the top left corner. I'll keep playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Guess it's similar to what you want to do. Hope it helps!